# Can I detect the text codec used in a string?

Tags: python

I'm reading a string from a file(which anybody can modify) and don't know which type of coded the string is. Is there any function like

```
 getCodec = mystring.getCodec()
```

which return something like

```
 getCodec = 'utf-8'
```

or

```
getCodec = 'ascii'
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such function, because files do not record what codec was used to write the text contained.

If there is more context (like a more specific format such as HTML or XML) then you can determine the codec because the *standard* specifies a default or allows for annotating the data with the codec, but otherwise you are reduced to guessing based on the contents (which is what tools like [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) do).

For a file that anyone can modify, you have no hope but to document clearly what codec should be used.

Comment: I also think there is more context, but there isn't. The most of the strings(about 5k) are in utf-8, but on some strings I've get the UnicodeDecodeError... :(

Comment: @alabamajack: the best you can do then is to use an error mode that either ignores such errors or replaces undecodable bytes with replacement characters (`?` or `�`).

Comment: Interestingly, there are systems that *do* record the encoding with every file (like IBM midrange). But of course, if they interact at all with the "outside world", they may receive files with no encoding information, or may send files to other systems that don't honor the encoding information provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 3rd-party [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(b'\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80')  # u'한글'.encode('utf-8')
{'confidence': 0.7525, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
>>> chardet.detect(b'\xc7\xd1\xb1\xdb')
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'EUC-KR'}  # u'한글'.encode('euc-kr')
```

NOTE: `chardet` is not foolproof, and if a file is small enough can easily guess wrong.

Comment: `chardet` is not foolproof, and if a file is small enough can easily guess wrong.

Comment: I should be noted that `chardet` is not shipped with Python but is a 3rd-party package.

Comment: nice idea, but cannot take this, because the python-installation then must be adapted manually on so much PC's...

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thank you for the information. I included your comment in the answer.

Comment: @Dolda2000, I added the word `3rd-party` explicitly. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `chardet` and have no chance of specifying the encoding in advance, I think your only remaining recourse is to simply guess at it. You could do something like this:

```
# Add whichever you want to the list, but only end it in a codec like latin1 that never fails
codecs = ["utf-8", "euc-kr", "shift-jis", "latin1"]

def try_decode(text):
    for codec in codecs:
        try:
            return text.decode(codec)
        except UnicodeError:
            continue
```

Comment: nice trick, a little bit dirty if you don't know what codec you need^^ ;)

Comment: Certainly, but since you do, indeed, not know it, I hardly think there's any other way to do it. I mean, this is basically what `chardet` does as well, only with a bit more sophistication.

Comment: I must say I was a little surprised that there is any codec that "never fails", but after a little experimentation, it does appear that you can always *decode* with `latin1` (at least on my Windows PC with Python 2.7). I think it's worth noting, particularly for those who are not 100% solid on character encoding issues (which frankly is most of us!) that while the `latin1` codec always "succeeds" in creating a Unicode string, that string could be complete garbage. It can happen that we would have been better off using, say, `shift-jis` and just ignoring/replacing a few bytes here and there.

Comment: @JohnY: Just for the record, there are tons of codecs that can never fail, since they simply map every possible byte to one, single, unique Unicode character. Common examples include the ISO-8859 encodings (Latin1 is ISO-8859-1), KOI-8, CP437, CP850 and CP1252, but there are many others also in common use.